# Latex rendering in README.md in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, latex

Is there any way to render LaTex in README.md in Pycharm? since it can handle `.tex` files, I assume it should be easy for that to do so.

Comment: It is possible in markdown cells  https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/10/28/dataspell-eap-20-brings-latex-support-jupyter-console-and-more/ so I believe it should be possible, though I believe not all tags are supported and I'm not sure how to make it happen.

Comment: @HappilyCoding Looks like it instructs adding Latex in jupyter, not README.md files. In my experience, adding Latex in Jupyters is OK and the same way does not work in README.md files.